# Getting error while re-deploying a versioned application in weblogic 10.3 server

Tags: java, weblogic

I have an EAR application already deployed on my weblogic 10.3 server. Now I did some modifications and re-created the EAR file and trying to re-deploy the application. But I am getting error as :

`You cannot distribute application 'sample.appl' without version. The application was previously deployed with version 'xxxx'`

Please help me on how to solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options, redeploy or delete the old deployment:

1 - For a redeploy to work, the deployment .ear file should be named exactly the same AND use weblogic version numbering in the manifest file. Specifically you should probably add something like the following to your `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_37-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Built-On: 2014-02-20-16-10-35
Weblogic-Application-Version: V4.0.0.2014-02-20-16-10-35
```

You can find a little more info about it here: http://tihlde.org/~eivindw/weblogic-production-redeploy-version-with-maven/

2 - Stop your old .ear file from the `deployments` link and then delete it. Then do your install as normal