# Encountering an error attempting to demonstrate Weblogic's 'Production Redeployment' feature

Tags: deployment, weblogic

I am trying to demonstrate Weblogic's 'production redeployment' feature with a very simple web app. I am running into an error "Changing the source location is not allowed for a previously attempted deployment."

Here is exactly what I did:

0) I configured an AdminServer in Weblogic on my local machine with no current deployments, built a very simple webapp with a few JSPs to put stuff in the session, packaged one version that puts 0.4 in the session and displays it, and another version that puts 0.5 in the session and displays it.

1) Install the sample webapp version 0.4:

```
emulcahy@ubuntu:~$ java -cp "/home/emulcahy/bea_1035/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar" weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user system -password weblogic1 -deploy -name redeploy -source /home/emulcahy/projects/redeploy/0.4/target/sample-redeploy.war

weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user system -deploy -name redeploy -source /home/emulcahy/projects/redeploy/0.4/target/sample-redeploy.war

<Apr 9, 2014 5:04:22 PM EDT> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating deploy operation for application, redeploy [archive: /home/emulcahy/projects/redeploy/0.4/target/sample-redeploy.war], to configured targets.> 
Task 8 initiated: [Deployer:149026]deploy application redeploy on AdminServer.
Task 8 completed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application redeploy on AdminServer.
Target state: deploy completed on Server AdminServer
```

2) At this point the webapp version 0.4 works, I can hit the JSP, there was much rejoicing. Next I want to deploy version 0.5, and demonstrate active sessions for both 0.4 and 0.5 in different browsers.

```
emulcahy@ubuntu:~$ java -cp "/home/emulcahy/bea_1035/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar" weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user system -password weblogic1 -redeploy -name redeploy -source /home/emulcahy/projects/redeploy/0.5/target/sample-redeploy.war

weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user system -redeploy -name redeploy -source /home/emulcahy/projects/redeploy/0.5/target/sample-redeploy.war

<Apr 9, 2014 5:05:23 PM EDT> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating redeploy operation for application, redeploy [archive: /home/emulcahy/projects/redeploy/0.5/target/sample-redeploy.war], to configured targets.> 
[Deployer:149007]New source location, '/home/emulcahy/projects/redeploy/0.5/target/sample-redeploy.war', cannot be deployed to configured application, 'redeploy'. The application source is at '/home/emulcahy/projects/redeploy/0.4/target/sample-redeploy.war'. Changing the source location is not allowed for a previously attempted deployment. Try deploying without specifying the source.
```

I do not understand how I can deploy an app without specifying the source. I tried uploading the 1st war file instead of using -source and it did not matter. I feel like I am missing something basic/obvious but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this today.  I am using Eclipse and WLS 10.3.6 with a JSF app.  I tried to remove and re-add the project and that didn't work.  What did was going into the WL management console, clicking deployments, selecting the box next to my app and hitting delete.  Then I restarted weblogic and added the app to it in  eclipse and it published normally.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are deploying an app with the exact same name. If you want to do that it needs to be in your original source folder `redeploy/0.4`. If you don't want to do that and want two versions of the app, you will need to name one of them differently. You can't have multiple apps named `sample-redeploy.war`, weblogic is confusing your new deploy with the existing version.

If you are redeploying a new version over the old one, you need to have version information in your manifest. Specifically `Weblogic-Application-Version`.

Check this answer from the other day - [Getting error while re-deploying a versioned application in weblogic 10.3 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948351/getting-error-while-re-deploying-a-versioned-application-in-weblogic-10-3-server/22948783#22948783)

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately this didn't change anything. I still get "The application source is at '/home/emulcahy/projects/redeploy/0.4/target/sample-redeploy.04.war'. Changing the source location is not allowed for a previously attempted deployment." when I do the -redeploy command with the other war (which I renamed *.05.war)